# How to automatically convert property values from String in Java?

Tags: java, properties

Suppose I've a bean that has many properties of many types like int, String, Date, etc... all primitive types of course. And I want to fill it with String representations of those values, without writing all the parsing code... how do I do that?

Comment: String and Date are *not* primitive types...

Comment: Wouldnt Date\Integer\Boolean.parseString do the job?

Comment: What kind of bean?  A plain java bean, or a Spring bean?

Comment: A java bean and I'd like not to write the parsing code, I meant that I didn't want to write the code with parseInt parse Date, etc..

Comment: *"And I want to fill it with String representations of those values,.."*  That is a terrible idea!  The bean should be redesigned to accept the actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

Bean frameworks like Spring do this for you. But if you want to write it yourself then you need use reflection to find the type required and then use the correct conversion code.

If you have a class like this:

```
public class MyBean {
    private int count;

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

And an application context like this:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="myBean1" class="MyBean">
        <property name="count" value="3"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then it should all just work fine for you. Have a look at the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators-propertyeditor) for some more info, the examples are better than the docs though.

Comment: Actually I use spring... Point me where is relevant

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you have a map of properties, for example:

```
name: "gotch4"
age: "21"
birthday: "7/21/2011"
```

and you want to create an instance of a hypothetical Person object, that has:

```
String getName()
int getAge()
Date getBirthday()
```

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) provides a good Java library to do this. Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#conversion

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.valueOf()`. You can pass this whatever objects need converting and it will do the rest. Note if any objects are passed in they will need a suitable toString method implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to instantiate a bean with values from a property file (ie Strings), then the `valueOf(String s)` method is your friend. All primitive type wrapper classes (`Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `Boolean`, `Character`, `Byte` and `String`) provide static factory methods called `valueOf`, taking a `String` argument.

Note that `Date` is not a primitive wrapper and does not fall into this category.

If you are interested I can post the code for a bean factory class I wrote that processes custom @Property annotations to create bean instances from property files.